# JPA, Simple One-To-Many Relationship Fetching Problem

Tags: spring, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, h2

Simple Fetch Problem I'm facing in a straight-forward OneToMany Relationship: One Author Many Books.

Here's Author :

```java
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "authors")
    public class AuthorEntity {
        @Id
        @GeneratedValue
        private UUID id;
    
        @Column(name = "first_name")
        private String firstName;
    
        @Column(name = "last_name")
        private String lastName;
    
        @OneToMany(
            mappedBy = "author",
            orphanRemoval = true,
            fetch = FetchType.EAGER
        )
        private List<BookEntity> books; // Getters and Setters
    }
```

Here's Book:

```java
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "books")
    public class BookEntity {
        @Id
        @Column(name = "id")
        @GeneratedValue
        private UUID id;
    
        @Column(name = "title")
        private String title;
    
        @ManyToOne(optional = false)
        @JoinColumn(
            name = "author_id",
            referencedColumnName = "id"
        )
        private AuthorEntity author;
    // Getters and Setters
    }
```

I saved an author and a book through their respective repositories and I checked everything is fine, and here's my query to fetch the author :

```
SELECT a FROM AuthorEntity a JOIN a.books WHERE a.id = :authorId
```

Now when I try to access `author.getBooks()` it says it is null, why doesn't it fetch ? Why do I always have to fetch the books separately ? What's the right query ?

Comment: Your query seems fine. Could you share the method that uses  this query?

Comment: While it shouldn't actually make any difference, you don't need the JOIN. You could just use `SELECT a FROM AuthorEntity a WHERE a.id = :authorId`.

Comment: @GreyBeardedGeek is right because `AuthorEntity ` has reference of `BookEntity`.

Comment: @edigu I've honestly used everything: repositories extending CrudRepository or JpaRepository, and I've also used Entity Manager, everything yet it just wouldn't fetch the books except in a separate query I do. author.getBooks() is always null.